Is this still a subordinating conjunction? — linking to a word or phrase instead of a subordinate clause
My book "visual guide to grammar and punctuation" says on pg 61.

subordinating conjunction. They link a subordinate (less important) clause to a main clause".."e.g. Tigers only hunt when they are hungry".

What happens if I change it to the still understood "Tigers only hunt when hungry" — now that "when" is linking to just a word (I guess the question also could be for just a phrase), is it still considered a subordinating conjunction?
thanks

Some grammarians would treat "when hungry" as a verbless clause. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/613666/would-we-consider-these-adjuncts-to-be-verbless-clauses

"when" serves the same role as in the original sentence. "they are" is simply elided.
